# Run the development version of R along side the stable version

Tags: r, ubuntu

I want to check a R package with R-devel under Ubuntu.

I installed R-devel based on
http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2012/08/installing-the-development-version-of-r-on-ubuntu-alongside-the-current-version-of-r.html

and I found the guide for Mac OS.
http://www.nicebread.de/how-to-check-your-package-with-r-devel/

I tried `R CMD check pkg --as-cran`, but it's still the stable R version to be used to check. How to let the R-devel be used to check?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have omitted the final step mentioned in the blog post you linked to. You need to change a number of environment variables to point to the new, development version of R. The post suggests creating a script to run the development version of R:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This assmues the dev version of R is installed in /usr/local/

export R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library::/usr/lib/R/library'}
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin:$PATH"
R "$@"
```

You can save this in a location in your `$PATH`, and name it for example `R-devel`. Make sure to make the script executable with `chmod`. Then you can launch R-devel like this:

```
R-devel CMD check pkg --as-cran
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry I'm new to Ubuntu. Do you mean `sudo vi /etc/profile.d/R-devel.sh`, add the above code, and `sudo chmod a+x /etc/profile.d/R-devel.sh`? But the command `R-devel` is still not found.

Comment: I'd say you put `R-devel` in e.g. `/usr/local/bin`. Remember to add where ever you save `R-devel` to your `PATH` environment variable. Assuming that `/usr/local/bin` is already in that path, just putting the script there will make it accesible system wide. If it is not there, just add something like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 5):

I have an [alternative method](https://logfc.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/r-devel-in-parallel-to-regular-r-installation/) based on advice from the bioc-devel mailing list. Assuming you want to install r-devel in your home directory, say in `~/R-devel/`, here is what you do:

First, set up environmental variables so that we don't need to repeat the names of directories. A directory for the sources and a directory for the compiled distro. Of course, they could be anywhere, wherever you like them to be:

```
export RSOURCES=~/src
export RDEVEL=~/R-devel
```

Now, get the sources + recommended packages:

```
mkdir -p $RSOURCES
cd $RSOURCES
svn co https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk R-devel
R-devel/tools/rsync-recommended
```

Next, build the R and packages:

```
mkdir -p $RDEVEL
cd $RDEVEL
$RSOURCES/R-devel/configure && make -j
```

That's it, you're done. Just save the following in an executable script somewhere to be able to run the development version:

```
#!/bin/bash
export R_LIBS=~/R-devel/library
R "$@"
```

Here is a script that saves the script automatically to your ~/bin/ directory:

```
cat <<EOF>~/bin/Rdev;
#!/bin/bash

export R_LIBS=$RDEVEL/library
export PATH="$RDEVEL/bin/:\$PATH"
R "\$@"
EOF
chmod a+x ~/bin/Rdev
```

Now you can simply run `Rdev` as if you were running `R`, and you will have the development version of R, which will install packages in `$RDEVEL/library`.